# Speaker Cross-Over Network and Power Design

Tags: power, audio, filtering

I have some speakers I want to drive from a single output: a 4Ohm 300W Subwoofer, a 6.44 Ohm 60W Midrange, and 2 8Ohm 3W Tweeters. All ratings are RMS.

I know that if I were to wire all of these in parallel, the equivalent resistance would be 1.52 Ohms, but there is different power at different frequencies, so calculating the max output amp voltage isn't trivial. If my cutoff frequencies would be something like 120Hz and 2kHz and assuming my music follows a pink noise spectral power distribution, my subwoofer is taking something like 40ish times more power than my tweeters. However, this is not reflected if one treats the whole network as an equvilant resistor.

How should I approach this? I would assume that using 1.52 Ohms as the equivalent resistance and using the limiting part of the network in terms of power, the tweeters, to designate the highest voltage would be faulty.
Should I instead use the pink-noise sound approximation to design my crossover with appropriate crossover frequencies and power distributions to each speaker, then just use the equivalent network resistance to calculate the max voltage the network can take? How exactly do I quantify the amount of voltage each speaker will see after all of the filtering?

Comment: What have you found so far? Any examples of circuits?

Comment: Music doesn't have the same power density as pink noise. I suggest reading this question and my answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353988/why-does-low-frequency-audio-take-up-more-power/ I also suggest to look up some guides on designing speaker crossover filters to learn how it is done. At the moment you are seeing issues that are really **not an issue**. For example: there will not be 1.52 ohms, the crossover filter will make sure a certain frequency goes to a certain driver (speaker) so at that frequency the amplifier will see about 8 ohms.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie With todays kids' listening to so called EDM and dubstep, this has shifted, but try playing say 1000 songs from various categories such as jazz and classical at the same time, it becomes much closer to pink. I did extensive simulation about this when I designed PA amplifiers for a living in MATLAB. Unlikley candidate for tipping of your amplifier energy hold-up design or just straight out bad amplifier design killer was Enya :-)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie you say music doesn't have the same power density as pink noise - clearly music can't be the same or it just comes out as noise but, for many pieces of music pink noise roughly approximates to the general spectral shape of music.

Comment: OK OK, with "music" I mean something that's played on acoustic instruments and recorded using a microphone. No electronic tricks involved. And IF your sound was pink noise, so flat over frequency, you'd hear a lot around 3 kHz and almost no base frequencies. Also most speakers have low wattage tweeters but high wattage woofers. How would that work if power was equally distributed over frequency?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie That's exactly how pink noise would work! Constant power over each octave. If you look at PA with big efficient (relativly speaking) 96 dB/W subwoofers, ~90 dB/W midrange and horn loaded compression drivers with 110 dB/W, you need to factor in the difference in efficiency too.

Comment: @Andyaka Another <--- This guy get's it! :-)

Comment: @winny aha a fellow studier of music spectrums LOL

Comment: Too broad - there are books about loudspeaker and crossover design. But to correct one misunderstanding : crossovers direct power to the appropriate driver, so you'll broadly see 4 Ohms at LF, 6.44 ohms at MF etc (plus maybe 0.5 ohm in the crossover) and something more complex at the crossover frequencies. To choose frequencies, first learn how each driver behaves; its directionality vs frequency, where its breakup frequencies are so you can avoid them, etc.

Comment: A simple google search for "speaker crossover design" gives this : https://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Tutorial/DesignBuildCrossover/ and this : https://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Calculator/SpeakerCrossover/

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the responses. I asked this question because google searches weren’t showing what I wanted; specifically, the voltage rails I should design my amplifier for. Mid frequencies may see a 6.44 ohm, but is the voltage amplitude at those midfrequencies for normal music the same as, say, at 100hz?